# Data Art/ Data Visualization Art/ Information Art

Tags: deep-learning, data, visualization, computer-vision, bigdata

Few days ago, I learned about data art/ data visualization art/ information art. I think I have interest in it. I want to see how I can use my data science skills in this area. However, I don't know how and where to start. I would be grateful if you guys could recommend books, videos or online tutorials for me.

Thanks

**Note:** I am a self-learning student of data science. I have basic understanding of data visualization. I mostly use deep learning in my work.

Answer (score 1):

A great web site with plenty of artistic projects to get inspirational ideas is Experiments with Google:

https://experiments.withgoogle.com/

You can also access their github to make your own experiences.

Then, here is an article about 8 artistic projects:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/8-impressive-data-science-projects-create-art-music-debates/

Applying Data Science in arts is very interesting but like any new artistic field, there is no clear rule, appart from trying innovative solution with your Data Science knowledge. For instance, you can paint music with this experiment:

https://experiments.withgoogle.com/paint-with-music

In addition to that, there are plenty of books for artist to find creativity and ideas. Maybe they could give you inspiration for projects with data science?

Here is an example of website about books for artists:

https://www.artworkarchive.com/blog/the-9-books-every-artist-should-have-on-their-shelf

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate you.